# How do you change the color of the highlighted text in the unix manual

Tags: unix, manual

I love the look of my black background terminal but when I try to use the unix manual the highlighted text "referring" to the unix command in question is black and invisible against my preferred back ground. Can anyone advise me on how to change the color of the highlighted text in the unix manual?

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the output from your man command to a file

```
man ls > junk.txt
```

You will see (if you view that file in a text editor) that man adds all kinds of control codes to the output to achieve its formatting.  These codes are interpreted by the terminal program you are using.

Because you haven't stated what terminal program you are using it is difficult to say what you need to do to turn on colour highlighting.  If you are on a mac you can open a terminal with various values for background and bold etc etc.

Obviously you figured out some way to make your background black.  That's a good place to start looking for how to turn on or modify the highlighting scheme you have in place.